# Is the ideal $I = \{f\mid f (0) = 0\}$ in the ring $C [0, 1]$ of all continuous real valued functions on $[0, 1]$ a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the ideal $I = \{f \mid f (0) = 0\}$ in the ring $C [0, 1]$ of all continuous real valued functions on the interval $[0, 1]$ a maximal ideal?

Comment: Why do you ask? What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: yes,infact I={f:f(c)=0} are the all possible maximal ideals

Comment: **Hint:** Try to determine the quotient $C[0,1]/I$ using the map $\phi: g\mapsto g(0)$. What is $\ker \phi$? What is ${\rm Im}~\phi$?

Comment: where is the compactness of [0,1] used?

Comment: Why do you think compactness would be used, @K.Ghosh?

Comment: in C(0,1) does this hold? i don't know

Comment: @K.Ghosh, Compactness is needed for the statement that every max ideal is of the form $I_c = \{f: f(c) = 0\}$, not this one.

Comment: This question is contained in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375400/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-real-functions-on-0-1

Comment: Related: [Proof that ideals in $C[0,1]$ are of the form $M_c$ that should not involve Zorn's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87277/721644)

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by Sigur, you can show that $\varphi : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} C([0,1]) & \to & \mathbb{R} \\ f & \mapsto & f(0) \end{array} \right.$ induces an isomorphism between $C([0,1])/I$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $C([0,1])/I$ is a field and $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Otherwise, you can prove it directly from the definition: Let $J$ be an ideal of $C([0,1])$ such that $I \subsetneq J$. In particular, there exists $g \in J \backslash I$ (ie. $g(0) \neq 0$). For every $f \in C([0,1])$:

$$f= \underset{ \in I \subset J}{\underbrace{\left( f- \frac{f(0)}{g(0)}g \right)}}+ \underset{\in J}{\underbrace{\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}g}} \ \in J$$

Therefore, $J=C([0,1])$ and $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $I\subset J$ and that inclusion is proper. Then $\exists f\in J$ with $f(0)\not= 0$. Clearly $f(x)-f(0)\in I\subset J$. Thus $f(x)-\Big(f(x)-f(0)\Big)\in J$ and so $f(0)\in J$, which is to say $J$ contains $1.\:\:$