# Characters of $C(X)$

Tags: banach-algebras

I showed that the character space $\Omega (\ell^1 (\mathbb Z))$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Now I am wondering if there is a similar identification for $C(X)$ where $X$ is compact Hausdorff with the sup norm?

Comment: What is your definition of 'the character space' of a Banach space? Besides $\ell^1(N)$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1(Z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The character space of $C(X)$ is homemorphic to $X$.

Proving this is a good exercise, but if you need a hint, the key ideas are contained in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375400/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-real-functions-on-0-1).

Comment: And is $C(X)$ homeomorphic to the character space of some space?

Comment: @Student: Thanks to Banach-Alaoglu, the character space of any unital commutative Banach algebra is compact. If not unital, it's still locally compact. But $C(X)S is locally compact only when X is finite.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments!