# Which of the following are true about the ring of continuous real valued functions C[0,1]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$. This is a ring under point-wise addition and multiplication. Which of the following are true:

(a) For any $x ∈ [0,1]$, the ideal $M (x) = \{f ∈ C[0, 1] : f (x) = 0\}$ is maximal.

(b)  $C[0, 1]$ is an integral domain.

(c) The group of units of $C[0, 1]$ is cyclic.

(d)  The linear functions form a vector-space basis of $C[0, 1]$ over $\mathbb R$.

i know a statement is true because it is for any x  not $every x$ therefore (a) is maximal ideal.

Because space is of real continuous real valued functions therefore (b) is true. I don't know how to prove or disprove (c) (d). thanx in advance

Comment: I believe (a) is true, (b) is false.  I'm pretty sure (c) is also false, how could it be cyclic?  It's way too big.

Comment: For b), consider the function $f$ that is $0$ up to $x=1/2$ and then climbs linearly, say $f(x)=x-1/2$.  Let $g(x)$ be the function which is $1/2-x$ up to $1/2$ and then $0$.

Comment: @gautam you ought to try searching for these questions individually. That would definitely get answers for a) and b). It is also just a bad idea in general to post a burst of more than three questions in a single post. Simple is better than complex.

Comment: d) is false for all sorts of reasons. You should be able to come up with some thoughts on that one.

Comment: @gregory grant  sir if i am not wrong here we are talking about continuous function so $C[0,1]$ is integral domain

Comment: @GautamSingla No, consider the function $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}[ll]\ 0 & 0\leq x\leq 1/2\\ x-1/2 & 1/2\leq x\leq 1\end{array}\right.$.  And let $g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}[ll]\ x-1/2 & 0\leq x\leq 1/2\\ 0 & 1/2\leq x\leq 1\end{array}\right.$.  Then $f$ and $g$ are both continuous and not identically zero, but $f\cdot g$ is identically $0$.

Comment: [Maximal ideals in the ring of real functions on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375400/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-real-functions-on-0-1)

Answer (score 2):

a),b) and d) have been treated in the comments. For c) you should notice that the constant functions give you a natural inclusion $\mathbb R^* \subset C[0,1]^*$ and $\mathbb R^* = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is not even countable, in particular not cyclic.