# $\operatorname{Max}(R)$ and my problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R:=\mathbb{R} ^{[0,1]}$ and let $m:={f\in R: f(0)=0}$. Show that $m\in \operatorname{Max}(R)$.
how to solve this problem?

Comment: Same solution as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/267627/29335, although strictly speaking this is a different question

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Evaluation at zero gives a ring homomorphism $R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: (...surjective!)

Comment: How is a definition Max(R)?

Comment: I guess it is the set of maximal ideals.