# Non unit version of Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

If we assume the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, how to prove the following statement:

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, $ C(X \to \mathbb R)$ is the set of continuous real valued functions. If $ A \subset C(X \to \mathbb R)$ is a closed algebra without the unit and separates points, then there is a (unique) point $ x_0 \in X$ such that $ A = \{ f \in C( X \to \mathbb R ): f(x_0 ) = 0$ }.

I don't know how to get started. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you add a non-zero constant function to $A$, the resulting algebra is dense by the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. So $A$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: @T.A.E. Wow. I don't even know this can combined with algebra. Why is $A$ an ideal? How does multiply a function in $C(X \to \mathbb R )$ and a function in $A$ result a function in $A$?

Comment: @T.A.E.: ... which more or less reduces the problem to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375400/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-real-functions-on-0-1

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for linking! Reading now.

Comment: @user112564: To amplify, let $A \oplus \mathbb{R} = \{f + c : f \in A, c \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  Verify that $A$ is a closed algebra that contains the unit and separates points, hence $A = C(X)$.  So every function $g \in C(X)$ can be written (uniquely) as $g = f + c$.  This will make it easy to see that $A$ is an ideal.

Comment: Missed the edit window.  I mean, verify that $A \oplus \mathbb{R}$ is a closed algebra, etc, and hence $A \oplus \mathbb{R} = C(X)$. (For the "closed" part you may need the Hahn-Banach theorem.)  And this also makes it clear that $A$ is maximal.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot! But I feel it's still hard for me to establish that $A \oplus \mathbb R$ is closed...

Comment: Hint: use Hahn-Banach to find a continuous linear functional that vanishes on A but not on 1. Suppose $f_n + c_n$ converges. Apply your linear functional.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks again. But I know Hahn-Banach only allows me to extend a functional from a subspace and maintain its norm. How do I find one that vanishes on $A$ but not on $\mathbb R$?