# What is the Krull dimension of $C(X)$ for $X$ infinite, compact and Hausdorff?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, commutative-algebra

> What is the Krull dimension of the ring of continuous real-valued functions on an infinite compact Hausdorff space?

If the Krull dimension is not finite, we will say that it is infinite, and not try to define it as a cardinal or an ordinal.

Of course the Krull dimension of $C(X)$ depends *a priori* on $X$, but I'd be very happy if it could be computed even in the most particular cases.

Comment: There are infinitely many prime ideals even for $X$ a closed interval: you can find a lovely proof here: http://pages.uoregon.edu/adding/notes/cont_ag.pdf - it may take some extra arguments to extend this fact to a proof that the Krull dimension is infinite.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078755/finding-a-space-x-such-that-dim-cx-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Krull dimension of $C(X)$  is infinite for any infinite compact Hausdorff space $X$.  By my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078897/86856), it suffices to show there exists a continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ which is not locally constant.  To show this, let $A=\{x_n\}$ be a countably infinite discrete subset of $X$.  For each $n$, by Urysohn's lemma there exists a continuous function $f_n:X\to [0,1/2^n]$ such that $f_n(x_m)=0$ for $m\geq n$ and $f_n(x_m)=1/2^n$ for $m<n$.  The sum $\sum f_n$ then converges uniformly on $X$ to a continuous function $f:X\to[0,2]$, and $f$ is injective when restricted to $A$.  Now let $y\in X$ be any accumulation point of $A$.  Since $f$ is injective on $A$ and every neighborhood of $y$ contains infinitely many points of $A$, $f$ is not constant in any neighborhood of $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer! I find the dichotomy in your other answer quite striking! I had never seen this condition of admitting a non locally constant real valued function before. I wonder if it is related to other properties (beside the Krull dimension of $C(X)$)? I agree that most of the job is done in the other answer, but I still find your argument above very ingenious (I wouldn't have found it by myself).

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen that exact condition anywhere else either--I just encountered it as exactly what I needed when writing my other answer.