# $R=C[0,1]$ be a commutative ring with identity. Is my proof correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

So Today , I face a problem , Here it is.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $R=C[0,1]$. For each $c\in[0,1]$ Let, $M_{c}=\{f\in C[0,1] | f(c)=0\}$
Show that ,

NOTE BEFORE SOLUTION :All $M_{c}$ are non empty just Define the zero function

1. $M_{c}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$
2. Any Maximal ideal of $R$ is of the form $M_{c}$
3. $M_{b}\neq M_{c}$ if $b\neq c$

My try.

1. Clearly, The quotient ring $R/M_{c}$ is a commutative ring with unity. Infact Suppose there is some $g+M_{c}\in R/M_{c}$ is nonzero that is $g(c)\neq 0$ for some $c\in[0,1]$ because $g\in R$ Choose $f$ such that , $f(c)=\frac{1}{g(c)}$ such $f$ exist as take $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{(c+1)g(c)}$ for Define $h(x)=g(x)f(x)-1$ Clearly, $h\in M_{c}$ so we have $$g(x)f(x)+M_c=1+M_c$$ or, $$(f+M_c)(g+M_c)=1+M_c.$$
   Thus $R/M_{c}$ is a field implying $M_c$ is a maximal Ideal.

Part 2: I am thinking.

3. Suppose for $b\neq c$ Choose, $t\neq 0$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(c)=0$(Because for the note) such functions exist in $C[0,1]$ ,$f(x)=\frac{t(x-c)}{b-c}$ Thus  $f\in M_{c}$ But $f\notin M_{b}$

My Question: Is my proof correct? If it is, is there a better proof exist? Then please mention.

Thanks in advance.

Well:I wanna thank Both who comments and I finally cooked up the proper proof, due to them only ,for 1 and 3 , I will try 2 later.

Comment: Hello , Thanks everyone My Sir Verified it yesterday , it's correct. But MSE people suggestions will be welcomed.Plz give vote man , I need badges.

Comment: For 1, define $\epsilon_c\colon R\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\epsilon(f)=f(c)$. This is a surjective homomorphism onto a field, so the kernel (which is $M_c$) is maximal. This simplifies $1$. For 2, how do you know that such a $k$ exists? For 3, how do you know such an $f$ exists? I do not see anywhere in your argument that you use the fact that the domain is $[0,1]$, and this must occur somewhere. For example, why does your argument in 2 not work for the continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with compact support, which have maximal ideals other than the $M_c$s?

Comment: Let me write it then why ? Such exist wait

Comment: You also do not justify $M_k\subset J$ in 2: you have produced a function in $J$ that is $0$ at $k$, but why does that say that $M_k\subset J$? I mean, $0\in J$, and $0$ is $0$ at $k$. So what?

Comment: "Thus in $f(k)g(k)+J=1+J$ for $k\in [0,1]$" is unintelligible to me. I have no idea what that means. And you still haven't shown $M_k\subseteq J$.

Comment: As a hint on 2: The proof I have in mind makes essential use of the fact that $[0, 1]$ is compact...

Comment: @DanielSchepler Indeed, that is an essential ingredient in the proof.

Comment: This is Problem 33 from $\S7.4$ of Dummit and Foote. There have been many posts about this problem on the site, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87277/proof-that-ideals-in-c0-1-are-of-the-form-m-c-that-should-not-involve-zorn). Does this post answer your questions?

Comment: I know But I want my own solution so

Comment: 1st part is correct right

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas First part suffers from the same issue as part 3: you should *prove*, ideally in an explicit way, that $f$ exists. Of course, the simplest way is to define $f$ not just by what it does at $c$, but by letting $f(x) = \frac{1}{g(c)}$ *for all* $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Ignore 1st one correct can you read it a bit

Comment: Because every continuous function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)-1$ form

Comment: Again, you say "choose $f$ such that..." but you never show that the set of all such functions is not empty. So the argument has a problem; it may not be hard to show that set is nonempty, but why leave it unsaid? Just produce an explicit, specific function and be done! Don't rely on your reader supplying the details you fail (and repeatedly refuse) to provide.

Comment: Well $f(c)=\frac{1}{g(c)}$ exist okay!!! Why as $g(c)\neq 0$ so And outputs of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ for all such $g$ such $f$ exist I hope you can see that, through your Brain, I am not a class 8 guy to mention every step some step should be thinkable too.

Comment: "Well, $f(c)=\frac{1}{g(c)}$ exists okay!!!" You haven't defined a function with domain $[0,1]$, you have only told us what value you want that function to take at the single point $c$. So you have not proven the existence of a function defined on all of $[0,1]$ with that property. Now, you asked for feedback on your writing: I am providing that feedback: your writing has issues, and I am pointing them out. If you don't want the issues with your writing pointed out, then don't ask people to comment on your writing.

Comment: Yes, that works (though the constant function $f(x)=\frac{1}{g(c)}$ that I had already mentioned is much simpler.)

Comment: Yeah, right!!! Thanks anyways helping throughout. And So what amazing is Our discussion cooked up a genuine different solution for 1. and 3. I think 2 but not at this moment. And these solutions are different from what are there On Dummit Foote solution!!! I can bet on that. I always try to do my own proof so This much long conversation, Hope you don't mind Sir, Actually I am not understanding your point but at the end I understand. Yes indeed $f(x)=g(c)^{-1}$ is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 2 is incorrect, sorry. You *must* use the fact that $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded, because the statement is false for $C(A)$ where $A$ is not a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

<sup>The maximal spectrum of $C(A)$ is homeomorphic to the Stone-Čech compactification of $A$, but you're not supposed to know it. In particular, $C(\mathbb{R})$ has *a lot* of maximal ideals that aren't of the form $M_c$.</sup>

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$. Then every $f\in M$ must vanish somewhere; define
$$
Z(f)=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)=0\}
$$
(the *zero-set* of $f$). Suppose $f,g\in M$ and that $Z(f)\cap Z(g)=\emptyset$. Then $Z(f)$ and $Z(g)$ are closed and disjoint. Consider $F=f^2+g^2$. Then $F(x)>0$ for every $x\in[0,1]$, because there's no point where $f$ and $g$ vanish together, so $F$ is invertible in $R$. However $F\in M$, which is a contradiction. This can be easily extended to any finite number of functions $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\in M$, so
$$
Z(f_1)\cap Z(f_2)\cap\dots\cap Z(f_n)\ne\emptyset
$$
Hence the family of zero-sets of the functions $f\in M$ is a family of closed sets with the finite intersection property, so it has nonempty intersection $C$ (this is what fails for $C(A)$ when $A$ is not compact).

Now prove that $C$ cannot contain two distinct points and finish up.

Comment: Yeah , Sir part 2 I couldn't think of, but trying. Closed and Boundedness is indeed needed.

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas For part 1 you've already been told about a simpler proof. Part 3 is actually needed to finish the proof of part 2.

Comment: @egreg Not sure you need part 3 to finish part 2...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, it's easier that way, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg The proof I have in mind uses that every cover has a finite subcover and does not use 3...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Also mine: the final point is that the nonempty intersection cannot contain distinct points. You find an open set where at least one function in $M$ doesn't vanish, it's essentially the same.

Comment: @egreg  So you don't actually need 3 to finish 2, right?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In order to see that $C$ cannot contain distinct points $c,d$, I can use that $M_c+M_d=R$. But that's just one way to finish.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to prove 1 is to consider the "evaluation at $c$" function, $\epsilon_c\colon R\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\epsilon_c(f) = f(c)$. This is easily verified to be a ring homomorphism, which is onto a field. Therefore, the kernel must be a maximal ideal, and the kernel is exactly $M_c$.

I am not convinced about your proof for item 2. How do you know such a $k$ exists? There is no justification. And there has to be one, because closely related rings do not satisfy condition 2: consider the ring $S$ given by
$$S = \{f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\mid f\text{ is continuous}\},$$
and let $J$ be the functions in $R$ of compact support, where a function $g$ has "compact support" if and only if there exists $N\gt 0$ such that $g(x)=0$ if $|x|\gt N$. It is easy to verify that $J$ is a proper ideal of $S$, and thus is contained in a maximal ideal $M$. However, for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $f\in J$ such that $f(c)\neq 0$, and therefore the same holds for $M$, so $M\neq M_c$ for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Where exactly does the argument you present fail for this $M$?

Also, you show that there exists *a* function in $J$ that takes the value $0$ at $k$. (And we already knew such a function existed anyway: the zero function, which definitely lies in $J$). But why are **all** functions that take the value $0$ at $k$ in $J$? You do not justify this claim either, and that is a problem.

For 3 you likewise need to explain why such an $f$ exists; it is not hard, but it needs to be done. For example, assuming without loss of generality that $b\lt c$, we can take the function
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text{if }{0\leq x\leq b}\\
\frac{x-b}{c-b} & \text{if }b\lt x\lt c\\
1&\text{if }c\leq x\leq 1.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then we can easily verify that $f$ is continuous, $f\in M_b$, but $f\notin M_c$. But an explicit function or an explicit justification for why such a function exists really needs to be given.

---

Here is a standard proof of 2. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ that is not contained in $M_c$ for any $c\in [0,1]$. We prove that $I=R$.

For each $c$ let $f_c\in I$ be such that $f(c)\neq 0$. It exists, since $I\not\subseteq M_c$. Since $f_c$ is continuous, there exists $\delta_c\gt 0$ such that if $x\in [0,1]$, $|x-c|\lt \delta_c$, then $f_c(x)\neq 0$.

Now the intervals $(c-\delta_c,c+\delta_c)$ form an open cover of $[0,1]$. Since the latter is compact, there is a finite subcover, corresponding to the points $c_1,\ldots,c_n$. Now let
$$f=f_{c_1}^2+\cdots+f_{c_n}^2.$$
This is a sum of elements of $I$, hence lies in $I$.  And since for every $x\in[0,1]$ there exists $i$ such that $f_{c_i}(x)\neq 0$ (since we have a cover), it follows that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Then $f$ is invertible in $R$, so $I$ contains a unit and thus $I=R$, as desired.

Comment: Yeah Did the same construction , basically motivation of such construction came from Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas What you did is invalid. You cannot construct a function $f$ by using the function $f$ that does not exist yet. $f(x) = \frac{f(b)(x-c)}{b-c}$ is not a valid way to define a function $f$. You don't know what $f(b)$ is, so how can you use it to define $f$?

Comment: Edit that you are correct.

Comment: Is that fine? I replaced

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas You don't say what $k$ is. Why leave things unclear and up in the air if you can give **explicit**, **unambiguous** formulas that actually define functions, instead of waving your hands so mightily? Also, you say "choose $f$ such that..." but in order to tell the reader to choose an $f$ with some properties, you  need to show that **there exist such functions**. And if you are going to have to prove that the collection of such functions is nonempty anyway, then just explicitly construct such a function and don't tell your reader to "choose". Just give them the answer.